# Can I have holidays during a von Humboldt research fellowship?

Tags: postdocs, germany

I am reading the Guidelines and Information of the Research Fellowships of the Alexander von Humboldt Foundation:

https://www.humboldt-foundation.de/fileadmin/Bewerben/Foerderung_waehrend_Aufenthalt/Forschungsstipendien_in_Deutschland/research_fellowships_guidelines.pdf

It is written (Section A.1.10)

> On principle, research fellows are not entitled to receive monthly fellowship payments if they are absent from the German host institute for a total of more than 14 days (continuous or accumulative) during the sponsorship period

Does it mean that, if my research period is 24 months long, that I cannot have more than 14 days (continuous or cumulative) as holidays, for example, to return home and visit family?

**EDIT:** Has someone a direct experience? Perhaps they reduce the salary, but is still possible to have a little of free time? 14 days in 2 years seem really very little

Thank you for any help and clarification!

Comment: If you ask the responsible officer (who is the only person able to give an authoritative answer), please come back and report the outcome.

Comment: It seems pretty clear. You can take no more than 14 days total and still get paid. The definition of "holiday" might need to be clarified, however. There are legal, national, or "bank" holidays some places that might not count.

Comment: It looks to me like a pretty clear statement that you get fourteen normal working days of vacation for a two-year fellowship (or five days for a six-month fellowship).  Absences for work are not counted: "Attendance  at  conferences  and  research trips  as  well as  visits  to  archives  and libraries  etc.,  that  are  essential  for carrying  out  the  proposed  research,  do  not  count  as  absences...."  Is there some possible subtlety beyond this that you are concerned about?

Comment: Under normal German working law, you are entitled to at least 20 days of vacation a year. This doesn't seem to apply for stipends (like the Humboldt-Fellowship), as mentioned e.g. here: https://studium.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/de/informationen-fuer-stipendiatinnen-und-stipendiaten (only in German), so it seems to be correct that you have only 14 days in total.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're right. Only 14 days off are allowed. If you need more days, but don't need to leave Germany, you can discuss the opportunity of arranging holidays with your academic partner.